# Did Qui-Gon know the Queen was a double?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

During the attack on Naboo, Padme used a decoy and posed as one of her own handmaidens. When she later reveals herself to the Gungans, Obi Wan looks genuinely surprised but Qui-Gon smiles.

Earlier in the film there are a few exchanges which indicates he either doesn't know (or perhaps he's teasing her?)

> Padme - You Jedi are far too reckless, the queen will not...
>
> Qui Gon - The queen trusts my judgement young handmaiden, and so should you.

Do we know for sure he's in the dark as much as anyone else?

Comment: Being a Jedi master implies _at least_ being able to assume the "I have known it all along" face under any circumstances. Even human consultants can do that !

Comment: The consensus of the Royal Handmaiden Society was that Qui-Gon certainly knew sometime before the scene in the Gungan swamp; how much before is still up for debate. Obi-Wan is a little iffier; my personal opinion is that Qui-Gon told him at some point, but Obi-Wan didn't believe it, so The Look in the swamp is basically "Told you so!" "So you did."

Comment: @Martha - The novelisation suggests that Qui-gon worked it out around the time of the R2D2 scene.

Comment: George Lucas says Qui Gon knew in the EP1 commentary,  I'd add this as an answer but I can't remember for sure if he said Obi Wan "looked surprised", but I don't think he looked surprised, bemused is more like it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [script](http://johanw.home.xs4all.nl/StarWars/starwars1.html) makes it clear that Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan both knew (or at least very strongly suspected):

> **PADME:** ***I*** *am Queen Amidala.*
>
> JAR JAR and ANAKIN are stunned.
>
> **PADME:** (points to Queen) *This is my decoy... my protection... my loyal bodyguard.*
>
> OBI-WAN and QUI-GON give each other a **knowing look**.

---

The Terry Brooks [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel)) gives an indication of precisely *when* Qui-Gon Jinn first began to suspect that something was amiss;

> Queen Amidala leaned forward, and a slender white hand came out to
>   touch the droid's domed casing. "Thank you Artoo-Detoo. You have
>   proven both loyal and brave." She glanced over her shoulder. "Padme."
>
> One of her handmaidens came forward. Qui-gon Jinn, listening to the
>   exchange with half an ear as he considered the problems that lay ahead
>   on Tatooine, noticed that **it was the young woman who had supported
>   the Queen's decision to escape from Naboo. He frowned. Except, it
>   hadn't been exactly like that . . .**
>
> "See to the cleaning up of this little droid." The Queen was speaking
>   to the girl. "Artoo-Detoo deserves our gratitude." She turned back to
>   Panaka. "Please continue with your report Captain."

and we have (canon) confirmation from Amidala herself that Qui-Gon definitely worked it out in [Star Wars: Queen's Shadow](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Queen%27s_Shadow)

> “You’re in select company, Senator,” Padmé told him. They paused to let a larger group pass them by. Several of them bade Senator Organa a good evening, but none of them overstayed their welcome. “Only a few people know the full lengths my most loyal bodyguards can go to, and **only one other person has ever figured it out on their own while we were in the middle of a deception.”**
>   “It was mostly chance, I think,” he said. “If I hadn’t caught you at just that moment, in that light, and with that expression on your face, it wouldn’t have occurred to me.”
>   “I am usually much better at controlling my expression,” Padmé admitted ruefully. “We were in a tighter spot than usual, though I suppose at least this time, the only thing at stake was my professional pride.”
>   “Who is the other?” Organa asked.
>   **“His name was Qui-Gon Jinn, a Jedi,”** Padmé said. As always, a feeling of almost overwhelming sadness threatened her when she thought of him. He had been patient and understanding of her, never asking for more than she was willing to give, and he had given all, in the end.

Comment: Not to mention that when they are going to look around Tatooine, Qui-Gon gets more upset when the 'hand maid' want's to come along than he has throughout the film to that point.

Comment: @xXGrizZ - I read that scene as being an indication that they **hadn't** worked it out yet. It was only after they had a chance to spend time with her that they realised what was going on/

Comment: This is supposed to be a KNOWING look? Ewan, Liam, you're fired. http://youtu.be/RNEQ3y1qPAM?t=3m10s

Comment: @Richard I think they knew the instant they met the double but were playing along because it was a good idea. It wasn't until the actual Queen started interfering and putting herself in danger that Qui-Gon had to say something. I could be wrong but the very first time I saw that scene I said to my self, 'he knows.'

Comment: @Plutor there's a bunch to hate in the movies, but you can clearly see them almost smirking/ holding in smiles. How much more obvious would an actor have to be? Tapping their noses and winking would hardly be how 2 ambassadors would behave during a diplomatic meeting!

Comment: As @Plutor referenced, this was *not* known based on the actors' performances. It also seems to clash with the scene where the queen kneels before the Gungan leaders in the swamp and asks for their help; Qui-Gon seems very surprised.

Comment: Agree with @Plutor. Qui-gon had the look of being told an amusing joke, not being told a joke he already knew.

Comment: @PaulDraper Hmm, but why would it be amusing to him that others had been fooled by the same two girls with no Force training they'd spent the last bunch of days being fooled by? Or that the girls in question were completely correct when they thought they _had_ managed to fool everyone. If there's no prior knowledge there isn't really anything funny in that situation. What's the joke he's finding amusing, in this case?

Comment: @TylerH I thought the surprise was because the Queen of the Naboo a) _kneeled_ to ask for aid and b) kneeled to the _Gungans_, who, according to the movie, they hadn't exactly been friendly towards or considered to be equals. Given that happens a bit _after_ Padme's identity reveal, it's a bit too late for the surprise to be identity based, isn't it?

Comment: @Shisa, "oh snap, she got us all pretty good. It was so good not even we knew it with our Jedi minding-reading magic" :) It doesn't have to be funny, but they seem to have a pretty good sense of humor.

Comment: @PaulDraper :) That's a good interpretation. ofc, character interpretation will vary, and I personally see QGJ as the kind of guy who'd get a bit pissed if he was wrong about something and OWK as the kind of guy who wouldn't see the humor in having unknowingly endangered someone they were supposed to be protecting - so for me the smile was immediate 'As if we didn't know' indicator. But I can see how it might be interpreted the other way too. :)

Answer (score 14):

One would think that a Jedi Master would know via the Force - the ultimate hunch, if you will. The exchange you quote above is by no means conclusive proof that he didn't know - it sounds to me as if he is using the fact that he knows she is the Queen to end the argument, and also to warn the Queen that she is going to blow her cover by acting 'above her station' (as a handmaiden).

Comment: It is precisely this implied warning that gave me the same impression.